# Doughnuts Chat Center Text Issue

Tags: reactjs, charts

Good Evening, World

I am facing issue with my react code. I want to display a "Center Text" in the middle of doughnut chart.

I have try lots of things but not working.

I am sharing my code please check and fix the issue.

```
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend);

const generateRandomData = () => {
  return Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
};

const data = {
  labels: ['Dataset 1', 'Dataset 2', 'Dataset 3', 'Dataset 4'],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: generateRandomData(),
      backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56', '#4BC0C0'],
    },
  ],
};

const options = {
  cutoutPercentage: 10,
  legend: {`your text`
    display: false,
  },
  plugins: {
    doughnutlabel: {
      labels: [
        {
          text: 'Center Text',
          font: {
            size: '20',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Doughnut data={data} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
};
```